# PayPal adaptive payment API Add item details + shipping cost

Tags: php, paypal

i'm using paypal adaptive payment API.
When a user submit the buy button on my site he redirect to paypal page,
in the paypal page he see only the cost amount for the item, and the seller store name. no shiping details , no item details . just seller name + amount.
what i'm missing? 
how can i add the shiping cost + the item details to the paypal page .

here is what i done so far:

```
$receiver[0] = new Receiver();
$receiver[0]->amount = $total_amount;
$receiver[0]->email =  $seller_email;


$itemData[0] = new InvoiceItem();
$itemData[0]->name = "test_item";
$itemData[0]->identifier = "123";
$itemData[0]->price = "10.00";
$itemData[0]->itemCount = "1";
$itemData[0]->itemPrice = "10.00";

$invoiceData->totalTax = "0";
$invoiceData->totalShipping = "10";
$invoiceData->item = $itemData;

$senderOptions = new SenderOptions();
$senderOptions->addressOverride = "1";
$senderOptions->requireShippingAddressSelection = "1";

$receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions();
$receiverOptions->customId = "customID";
$receiverOptions->receiver = $receiverInvoice;
$receiverOptions->invoiceData = $invoiceData;
$receiverOptions->SenderOptions = $senderOptions;


$receiverList = new ReceiverList($receiver);


$requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");

$payRequest = new PayRequest();
$payRequest->requestEnvelope = $requestEnvelope; 
$payRequest->receiverOptions = $receiverOptions;
$payRequest->receiverList = $receiverList;
$payRequest->actionType = "PAY";
$payRequest->cancelUrl = "http://pay.php?success=cancel";
$payRequest->returnUrl = "http://pay.php?success=true";
$payRequest->currencyCode = "USD";
$payRequest->ipnNotificationUrl = "http://replaceIpnUrl.com";



$adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService($sdkConfig);

$payResponse = $adaptivePaymentsService->Pay($payRequest);

$ack = strtoupper($payResponse->responseEnvelope->ack);

     if ($ack == "SUCCESS") {

       $payKey = $payResponse->payKey;
        $payPalURL = PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL. $payKey;

    } else {
    die();
    }

    header('Location:' . $payPalURL);
```